# Improve a big mysql select performance

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a select to get products from sellers that an custormer follows.
this products has likes, comments, need to count likes, need to count comments and show another things.
I have a `where user in` to get custumers that user follows.

The problem is, this select is taking a while and I'd like to know if I can improve it somehow. All my ids are keys.

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, count(distinct comentarios.id) as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2 

from products p 

join users c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
left join likes on likes.post = p.id
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id and comentarios.delete = 0  
left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = ?

where (p.user in (select following from following where user =? and block=0) or p.user=?) and p.delete='0'
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit ?
```

explain:
[image]

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about the execution of that query?

Comment: As well SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN

Comment: @NicoHaase I add it in my question!

Comment: @Strawberry I add the explain in my question

Comment: Thanks for the progress report

Comment: the explain was from my local host. that's why there is not many rows.

Comment: As the statistics, which depend on the actual data, can play a big role for the optimizer deciding which index to use, you should always test with a realistic set of data. A test on a test database with only a few rows, whereas the real live database has much more rows, might give misleading results.

Answer (score 4):

Apply Index in **products** table with delete and user column (use composite index).

Apply appropriate index ind **users** table

```
SELECT c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, COUNT(DISTINCT likes.user) AS likes_count, COUNT(DISTINCT comentarios.id) AS comentarios_count, COUNT(DISTINCT l2.user) AS count2 

FROM products p 

LEFT JOIN users c ON p.user=c.id 
LEFT JOIN profile_picture pp ON p.user = pp.user
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.post = p.id
LEFT JOIN comentarios ON comentarios.foto = p.id AND comentarios.delete = 0  
LEFT JOIN likes l2 ON l2.post = p.id AND l2.user = ?

WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL AND  (p.user IN (SELECT following FROM following WHERE USER =? AND block=0) OR p.user=?) AND p.delete='0'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT ?
```

Use above query may give you better performance

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

From your explain, it looks you don't have an index key `products` on `(user, delete, id)`.  this is likely the biggest bang for the current query.

I'm going to assume since you're asking this you don't know about `EXPLAIN` and even if you did, probably would have difficulty parsing out direction to move on what to do if you did read it.

In the short, assuming you've no major storage/memory issues to deal with and can add indexes to your tables, I would suggest you need to have the following indexes on your tables:

- Composite index for table `products` on `(user, delete, id)`
- Composite Index for table `likes` on `(post, user)`
- Composite index for table `comentarios` on `(foto, delete)` .  **I HATE COLUMNS NAMED AFTER RESERVED WORDS (like DELETE)!!!!**
- Composite index for table  `following` on `(user, block)`

This will make the joins efficient but is not 100% covering, which is likely not desirable in this case from your select values.

There may already be existing indexes that fit the above, any that start wit the values above (in the exact order) in the table it's noted for will be good enough.  For example, if you've an index for table `likes` on `(post, user, some_other_column)` it will already provide everything needed by my suggestion of index on `(post, user)`.  The key is the values needed in from it has to be ordered exactly the same.

Now there's a ton of nuance to indexing and a lot you'll want to learn, but this should unblock your work.

Just tossing out a few additional things:

- You should name foreign keys after the table and column they relate to.  For example `comentarios.foto` would be better named `comentarios.products_id` if indeed it's the id from the products table.  Such clear naming will help prevent bugs/errors, improve efficiency writing new queries, and minimize loss of sanity for future developers trying to grok your schema.
- As mentioned by several commenters,  learn about how to read a Mysql `EXPLAIN` on you queries.  Just literally add the keyword `EXPLAIN` before your query and run it. The result lays out what the query engine initially plans to do to execute your query (may actually deviate during execution, but typically pretty spot on) .  From this you can see where an index may be needed to improve execution.

Comment: Thank you friend! I'll try your tips!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ray's excellent suggestions for indexes I'd further suggest to try and rewrite the `IN` to an `EXISTS`. Optimizers rarely to never can do that themselves, but it's usually cheaper. So

```
p.user in (select following from following where user =? and block=0)
```

should read

```
exists (select * from following where user = ? and block = 0 and following = p.user)
```

.

Create a composite index on `following (user, following, block)` or `following (following, user, block)` to support the subquery for the above `EXISTS`. Here it's hard to guess which of `user` and `following` has the better selectivity. They're probably quite similar, so both orders should do. To be sure, check which column has more distinct values in the table and put that first.